# Invariant decimal variable

Tags: c#, .net

Please observe following simple code. Why the variable inVarient prints without decimal point. I want decimal point, how to achieve it?

```
decimal actualVal = 1247315.93m;

string inSwedish = actualVal.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"));

decimal inVarient = decimal.Parse(inSwedish, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(inSwedish);  //prints 1247315,93 (as intended)
Console.WriteLine(inVarient);  //prints 124731593 (I need 1247315.93)
Console.Read();
```

Comment: I suspect, you have to parse it back with `sf-SE` culture.

Comment: This is silly. To round-trip data as text, the 2 cultures very much need to match. You are using separate and incompatible cultures on purpose.

Comment: The `,` is treated as a thousands separator in the invariant culture.

Comment: +1 for "this is silly".

Comment: @HenkHolterman I believe the OP simply created an oversimplified code sample for demonstration purposes.

Comment: And the simplification highlights the error very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're trying to parse a *string* that represents a decimal formatted with the *Swedish* culture but you're trying to parse it with the *invariant* culture, which won't treat a comma as a decimal point. You need something like this:

```
decimal actualVal = 1247315.93m;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE");

string inSwedish = actualVal.ToString(culture));

decimal invariant = decimal.Parse(inSwedish, culture);

Console.WriteLine(inSwedish);  
Console.WriteLine(invariant.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

Swedish culture uses `,` as a decimal separator, the invariant culture uses `.`, so when it parses a string using the comma as a separator it just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your decimal point disappears here is because in the invariant culture, a comma is a *thousands* separator, not a *decimal* separator. Thus, it assumes it can safely ignore commas when parsing a numeric text.

If you go back and forth from a culture to another, this kind of thing is to be expected.

I don't know what your real context is but if you want to recover the numeric as it originally was before it was made a string, you must **either use consistent formatters throughout your code** or **not storing decimals into string variables only to parse them back to decimal again**.

If there's no need to serialize anything the latter is the way to go.